# Trigger on dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, eventtrigger

I am creating dynamic elements and upon click of a another button, a click event on the dynamically generated element need to be executed. I know `on()` jquery method has such a functionality but do not know how to apply in my context. I would be glad if someone could help.

**HTML Code:**

```
<h2></h2>
<button>generate new element</button>
<p class="generateEvent">Event</p>
```

**My jQuery Code:**

```
$(function(){

    $("button").click(function() {
        $("h2").html("<p class='test'>click me</p>")
    });

    $('.generateEvent').click(function(){
        $("p").trigger("click", function(){
            alert('you clicked me again!');
        });
    });
});
// Method two:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PzSYM/399/

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `.trigger()` call?

Comment: In fact I am triggering the click event

Answer (score 3):

You can use `on()` by binding the event to the target's parent container which is already on the page when you first load the page. Like this way:

```
$('#parent').on('click','.target',function(){
   //do something..
});
```

Comment: I second this, `on()` is the latest jquery function. The other function like `live
()` is deprecated or removed to the latest library of jquery...

Comment: In fact this is a simplified version of what I want. I am actually creating a custom event login.validate and calling the event using trigger() but for dynamic elements, it's not working

Comment: This is the actual problem which I am not able to sort using the on() method http://jsfiddle.net/PzSYM/400/

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
$("p").bind("click", function(){
alert('you clicked me again!');})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sCgCj/